# Vue js Select default value not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm learning Vue js and I’m listing some data from database using `v-for`. There is a nested `v-for` where I list tours titles inside a `select`. So when I select a title, its description is listed below.

I’m trying to set a default value using `option` above `option` with the nested `v-for`. I tried based on v-model = "selected[item.id]" but I could not make it work. It's getting blank. is it possible to set "Select a tour" before users open the `select` box using the same `v-model`?

[image]

[image]

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in hosters" v-bind:key="item.id" class="col-md-6 mb-50">
    <h4 class="mb-0">{{ item.name }} {{ item.lastname }}</h4>

    <div class="tour-options-select">
        <select :id="'select-suggestions' + item.id" name="tour-options-dropdown"
                v-model="selected[item.id]" class="tour-options-dropdown"
                @change="showTour = selected">

            <option selected disabled>{{ selected.value }}</option>
            <option v-for="(tour, key) in item.tours" :key="key"
                    :value="tour.tourID">
                        {{ tour.title }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    // here each post is listed by selecting its title
    <div v-if="toursObj[selected[item.id]]" class="tour-suggestions">
        <div class="tour-list">
          <div class="tour-list-title">
             <p>{{ toursObj[selected[item.id]].title }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tour-list-description">   
                <p>{{ toursObj[selected[item.id]].description }}</p>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div @click="showTour = false" class="close-suggestions">
          <span>X</span>
       </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

vue

```
let app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      hosters: {},
      selected: {
        value: 'Select a tour'
      },
      toursObj: {},
      advise: {
        isTrue: null,
        message: 'No hoster found'
      },
   },
  methods: {
   searchHoster: function () {
    axios.post('http://localhost/search/searchHoster.php', { "city": this.city }).then((response) => {

        if (response.data != "No hoster found") {
            this.advise.isTrue = false;
            this.hosters = response.data.hosters;
            console.log(this.hosters);

            const TOURS_OBJ = {};
            this.hosters.forEach(hoster => {
                hoster.tours.forEach(tour => {
                    TOURS_OBJ[tour.tourID] = tour;
                });
            });
            this.toursObj = TOURS_OBJ;
        } else {
            this.advise.isTrue = true;
            console.log(response.data);
        }

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/phxjdbku/

Comment: Have you tried with empty `value` for the default option and hoping that a NULL `v-model` value will match the empty `value` ?

Comment: Hi Ivo. Yes, I did it but it didn't work.

Comment: hi palash, I pasted a link to jsfiddle. Please see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your example on JSfiddle has the following issues:

1. The `v-model` for SELECT references `item.id` - but your items do not have such a property
2. The `v-model` for SELECT specifies that your `selected` object has keys corresponding to the ID of each hoster - but your data section defines `selected` as a String instead of Object
3. Your default option does not have a `value` attribute
4. Your default option does not say `Select a tour` but instead interpolates `selected.value` - and we already know that `selected` can not potentially have such a key

Please take a look at the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7npu56mx/).

Comment: Ok. I noticed that you defined fixed values for `selected { 1: null, 2: null, },` and it works. So, how can I do if I my results will vary according to the number of results from the input seach? Users will search for the hosters of desired city they want to find a hoster.

Comment: For each SELECT where you need a default option to be pre-selected you need the variable which `v-model` refers to to be defined - even with a NULL value. Since you have decided to point your `v-model` to `selected[key]` you need those `keys` to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this answer as a note to myself or someone else who might encounter a similar issue with VueJS 3:

VueJS renders the initial:

```
<option selected disabled>{{ selected.value }}</option>
```

but then quickly re-renders the form with the `data` values:

```
   data: {
      selected: {
        value: 'Select a tour'
      },
      ...
   },
```

And since there's no `<option>` tag that has the value of `Select a tour`, the form renders without a selected option.

The fix is then to make sure the initial data matches the form. So something along the lines of this:

```
...
   data: {
      selected: {
        value: '-1'
      },
      ...
   },
...
<select ...>
  <option selected disabled value="-1">{{ selected.value }}</option>
...
```

Hope that helps

A possibly more self-describing variation:

```
const placeholder_value = -1;
...
   data: {
      selected: {
        value: placeholder_value
      },
      ...
   },
...
<select ...>
  <option selected disabled value="placeholder_value">{{ selected.value }}</option>
...
```